# Entire image clickable in IE

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer

I'm working on a project, when you hover it you should click it. It works perfect in all browsers. But for some reason it doenst work in IE

**Live Demo:**
http://jewelbeast.com/imghover/rounded.html

**HTML:**

```
<div class="vertical-smallborder">
    <section>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x600" />
        <div class="text">
            <span>
                <h1>This is a title</h1>
                <p>This is an example of a description.</p>
                <p>The entire image is a link!</p>
                <a class="entire" href=""></a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.vertical-noborder section span a.entire{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I hope someone knows the problem.

Comment: Why make it so complicated? Just wrap everything in the A tag rather than trying to fake it with absolute positioning. HTML5 allows anchors wrapping block level elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is definitely more complicated than it needs to be-- unless there's some reason that you need to absolutely position elements, you shouldn't.

I believe there are two undesirable behaviors in your code in IE:

1. `Margin-left: -250px` in the div is pushing the element off-screen
2. The `z-index` of the elements is putting the `img` above the `a` tag. ([link](http://alex.leonard.ie/2013/01/27/ie-bug-text-ignores-z-index-of-higher-elements/))

Rather than trying to fix these bugs in IE, rewrite what you have to wrap the `img` in the `a` tag.